# Чтение целого числа из бинарного файла

Tags: java, delphi, файлы

Есть бинарный файл, в котором много чисел типа Int. Я их специально записывал на Delphi что бы читать на Java. Теперь когда читаю с помощью readInt используя и RandomAccessFile и DataInputStream получается одно и тоже. Цифры что были на Delphi и те что получились после чтения на Java оказались разные.

Если кто сталкивался с такой проблемой, подскажите. Или я что-то делаю не так?

Comment: @Mansur просто мысли вслух: записать в файл 1234 и прочитать, а там уже понятней будет что к чему.

Answer (score 2):

`Integer` в Delphi и `int` в Java оба 4 байтовые знаковые. Вроде все должно работать, но проблема в том, что есть 2 способа представления битами отрицательных величин. Т.н. 1-е и 2-е дополнение. В Java используется 2-е дополнение, в Delphi видимо 1-е дополнение.

Подробнее [здесь](http://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%C4%EE%EF%EE%EB%ED%E8%F2%E5%EB%FC%ED%FB%E9_%EA%EE%E4_(%EF%F0%E5%E4%F1%F2%E0%E2%EB%E5%ED%E8%E5_%F7%E8%F1%EB%E0))

Comment: А может просто порядок байт разный?

В Java сетевой (тот что вернет htonl(host_int32) из libc), а в Дельфи, наверное, native для x86.

Comment: @avp это наверное тоже. В Java порядок big-endian, в x86 порядок little-endian - так что ты прав :)

Answer (score 0):

```
for (int i=0; i < SIZE_Y; i++) {
    for (int j=0; j < SIZE_X; j++) {
        inp.read(buffer);
        int nextInt = (buffer[0] & 0xFF) | (buffer[1] & 0xFF) << 8 | (buffer[2] & 0xFF) << 16 | (buffer[3] & 0xFF) << 24;
        test_data[j][SIZE_Y - i - 1] = nextInt;
    }
}
```

[Взято отсюда](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5078100/fast-reading-of-little-endian-integers-from-file).

Comment: IMHO байты в 32-bit целом проще переставить так:

      int x = 0xa1a2a3a4, res;
    
      res = 
        ((x >> 24) & 0xff) |
        ((x >> 8) & 0xff00) |
        ((x << 8) & 0xff0000) |
        x << 24;

Правда, проверял на Си, но насколько помню Java, должно быть так же.